# how does python deal with yielded dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having some trouble dealing with dictionary yielded (in for loop) to two different functions , in my case I create dictionary in function and sometimes yield it to two functions, function1 fills 4 keys (then writes to csv), function2 fills with 6 keys (4 keys are same as function 1 then writes to csv) however, the 4 keys values are always correct but the extra 2 keys are being copied to function 1 (whenever function 2 is also yielded). When they are ran alone they both run correct.

The code is scrapy spider using `scrapy crawl test -o test.csv`.
I have fixed it by inserting the two missing keys (filled them empty) in function1. My question is why does this overlap happens?

Small function that shows similar behavior (I hope Google gives same results as mine)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from urllib.parse import quote,urlparse

class Stackoverflow(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'test'
    start_urls=['https://www.google.com/search?q=SQL',
        'https://www.google.com/search?q=hello+world']

    def parse(self,response):
        item=dict()
        item['hello world'] = 123
        links= response.xpath('//div[@class="r"]/a')
        temp_list = []
        for link in links:
            small_dict=dict()
            if "wikipedia.org" in  urlparse(link.xpath('@href').extract_first()).netloc:
                small_dict['wikipedia'] = link.xpath('@href').extract_first()
                temp_list.append(small_dict)
            if "learnpython.org" in urlparse(link.xpath('@href').extract_first()).netloc:
                small_dict['learnpython'] = link.xpath('@href').extract_first()
                temp_list.append(small_dict)
        for my_dict in temp_list:
            for func,link in my_dict.items():
                yield Request(link,callback=getattr(self, f"{func}"),meta={'item':item})

    def wikipedia(self,response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['title']=response.xpath('//title/text()').extract_first()
        image = response.xpath('//a[@class="image"]/img/@src').extract_first()
        item['image_title'] = response.urljoin(image)
        yield item

    def learnpython(self,response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['title']=response.xpath('//title/text()').extract_first()
        yield item
```

Comment: You need to show your code. I expect you're sending the same dictionary in both cases.

Comment: Please show a *minimal* example that shows the behaviour you're having problems with.

Comment: @DanielRoseman the code is pretty long, I hope I delivered the idea correctly though

Comment: I think your problem is that you use scrapy to write for the csv hence all output dictionary keys must be present in the csv, while you previously depended on scrapy to fill them. this explains why when ran alone they are automatically empty

Comment: @wishmaster this doesn't explain why when both are ran the output overlaps though i.e values are being sent to the output of function1

Comment: If sounds like you have one dictionary reference with two things writing to the same dictionary. When you yield the dictionary, it's just a reference to the same dictionary each time.

Comment: @00 is it okay if I create a small script that shows the same behavior ?

Comment: That would be ideal @AmjasdMasdhash.

Comment: @MarkMeyer one dictionary initiated from one function but yielded to two functions

Comment: But it's still one dictionary @AmjasdMasdhash — an example will really help/

Comment: You don't have to show the full code. But you *do* have to show some code that demonstrates the problem. As others have said, it sounds like it's just one dictionary.

Comment: @DanielRoseman please check update (the output depends on what Google gives though different proxies gives different output)

Comment: @MarkMeyer check update please

Comment: @00 update should  give you an idea of what is going on

Comment: As we said, you're yielding the same dict, `item`, in every iteration of the loop.

Comment: @DanielRoseman then why are the replica keys values correct?

Comment: What "replica" keys? The dict keys are correct, because that's how they are set inside the two functions/methods. The additional key-value pairs in one function result from the dict being mutated in the other function.